# 4k resolution for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution, hdmi

I just got a new 4k monitor LG-27UL500, I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS but I can't set the resolution higher than 1920*1080. There a some similar threads about this topic ([this one for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307271/can-t-enable-4k-resolution-on-external-display)), but none of them seemed to work for me.

Maybe it could be because my GPU has a mini-display port connector, and I'm using an adapter to connect to the HDMI of the monitor?

**Here are my specs:**

OS: 18.04.5 LTS

GPU: [NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL, Quadro P620](https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/design-visualization/quadro-product-literature/quadro-pascal-p620-data-sheet-593981-us-nv-r3-web.pdf) , output = mini-display port

Monitor: [LG27UL500](https://www.lg.com/it/monitor/lg-27UL500-W), input = HDMI

GPU drivers (got with `dkms status`):

```
nvidia, 510.39.01, 4.15.0-167-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.39.01, 4.15.0-169-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.39.01, 4.15.0-171-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.39.01, 4.15.0-173-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.39.01, 4.15.0-175-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.39.01, 5.4.0-104-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.39.01, 5.4.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.39.01, 5.4.0-107-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Someone suggested that the problem could be an outdated GPU driver. So I tried to manually download drivers from NVIDIA website and install them. Unfortunately, this is the message that I get:
[image]
I tried to install the drivers as soon as I started the PC, but it did not change.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the output of my `xrandr -q`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  3840x2160_24.00 (0x2e9) 266.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4056 end 4456 total 5072 skew    0 clock  52.59KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2192           clock  23.99Hz
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x367) 712.340MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4152 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock 134.10KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2161 end 2164 total 2235           clock  60.00Hz
```

However, if I try to activate the 3840x2160 mode with command `xrandr --addmode DP-5 3840x2160_60.00` (or `24.00` instead of `60.00`), this is what I get:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

I still have to try with a cable without adapter, I hope I can find one today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I tried playing with xrandr too...

The only thing that worked for me was to replace the mini display port adapter with a 4k capable mini display port to HDMI 2.1 cable.

In your case, since the monitor supports it, use a mini display port to display port cable, as those tend to be more reliable than the mini DP to HDMI adapters.

Comment: So, just by replacing the connector, it worked? Because it's not like i can see the option of 4k resolution but it doesn't work, I just can't see the option at all! Did you have to install something, like a driver? And sorry for the newbie question, but what is xrandr exactly?

Comment: No drivers required. Modern video cards / video drivers are very intelligent, and are able to negotiate with the display to determine what resolutions, bit depth, and refresh rates will be available based on bandwidth and supported features. 

I found a huge variance in adapter quality in the display port to HDMI adapters, and found that if the adapter is poorly shielded or there is too much cross talk on the wires when the video card / drivers and the monitor are handshaking the system will simply exclude options which aren't possible on the current connection.

Comment: Turns out this was the solution. SImply changing the cable to a mini display port to display port one did the trick

Answer (score 2):

## What is `xrandr`?

This question was posted in comments by OP.

At the command line type: `xrandr -q`

```
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   3840x2160_54.00  53.98*+
   3840x2160     30.00 +  24.00    29.97    23.98  
   4096x2160     24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      74.93    59.91  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1280x720      60.00    30.00    59.94    29.97    24.00    23.98  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Above is example of a 4K screen that is working. Like yourself a custom dongle converting ThunderBolt 3 to HDMI is used. Consequently a custom refresh rate of 54 Hz had to be setup.

Start off by putting your own `xrandr -q` output into your question. Then everyone can help you fine-tune your setup from there.

Comment: Added more details in my post

Answer (score 1):

For UHD (3840x2160) at 60fps HDMI 1.4 is the minimum required.

The adapter can be the issue, depending on the HDMI version it provides.

As said before you can check with `xrandr` if a profile for 4k exists
if not you can create mode resolution using `xrandr` and `gtf`

First use `gtf` to create a mode line
`60` is framerate you can set an higher framerate if your monitor support it, and if you use an HDMI 2.1 cable

```
gtf 3840 2160 60
```

This will generate something like this

```
# 3840x2160 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 134.10 kHz; pclk: 712.34 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.34  3840 4152 4576 5312  2160 2161 2164 2235  -HSync +Vsync
```

Then create a new mode using xrandr and parameters from previous command

```
 xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.34  3840 4152 4576 5312  2160 2161 2164 2235  -HSync +Vsync
```

Now you need to add the mode to the desired output, in your case it seems to be `HDMI-0`

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 3840x2160_60
```

Finally apply the new mode

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160_60
```

It this does not work maybe should you consider using a MiniDisplayPort to DisplayPort cable to avoid the adapter

EDIT:

Add vertical and horizontal refresh rate to `Xorg.conf` in the monitor section

```
Section "Monitor
  Identifier "External Monitor"
  Vendor "LG"
  ModelName "LG-27UL500"
  HorizSync  30-82
  VertRefresh  56-76
EndSection
```

Restart Xorg or Reboot and it should work.

Cheers

Comment: I'm trying to apply this solution. I successfully did the first steps, but when I have to add the mode, with command `xrandr --addmode DP-5 3840x2160_60.00`, I get errors:
`X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44`

Comment: You can see the post, I added details there

Comment: @SilentCloud You can try to add vertical and horizontal refresh rate to Xorg.conf check my EDIT

Comment: one major problem could be that I don't have that file. Maybe something went wrong with the installation of my GPU drivers?

Comment: in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` create a file named `99_monitor.conf` and put config in it.

Comment: So I tried to create the file you suggested, I copied in the config in your EDIT. The `--addmode` command still gave an error, so I rebooted but then graphic interface didn't start. I had to delete the file from remote and reboot again. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe try to put `24-76` in `VertRefresh`, but the issue can also be related to the driver. I'm not very familiar with NVIDIA, this solution works great for AMD devices.

If X won't start you should check the log file to see where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Return your LG 27 UL500W monitor to the shop you bought it.

- Display Port has some bugs and it won't be fixed to work on 4k mode.
- Display itself often is going to blackout or having a lot of noises.
- It is a flimsy product and you can't fix.