# How can I get full (2560x1440) resolution on my external display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, hdmi, displayport, 4k-monitor

I am using AOC Q3279VWF as a monitor, but am only able to reach 1920x1080 resolution. I would like to achieve the full 2560x1440 resolution of the monitor. This is listed as an option in the display settings as well as with xrandr, but the screen goes black when I switch to this mode.

Pastebin of sudo lshw: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/RR76KcVKKk/

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 144
    Memory at eb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 146
    Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at ed000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I do not know whether it's relevant, but one thing I found curious, is that xrandr -q lists my HDMI connection as a display port (DP-3).

All help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
Inspired by [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307289/1653309) solution, I decided to try the same. Using the read-edid package, I retrieved the monitor's EDID as such:

```
sudo get-edid -b 11 | parse-edid
1
1
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Only trying 11 as per your request.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 11
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Q3279WG5B"
    ModelName "Q3279WG5B"
    VendorName "AOC"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 43 of 2017
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 730 430
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-114
    VertRefresh 48-76
    # Maximum pixel clock is 300MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x960, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline    "Mode 13" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 296.00 2560 2568 2600 2666 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 11" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 12" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 14" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 15" 27.00 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 16" 156.00 1280 1376 1512 1744 1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 13"
EndSection
```

From that list, I detect two modes that use 4K resolution, namely Mode 0 and Mode 1. I then added these two modes as new modes in xrandr, as such:

```
xrandr --newmode "Mode0" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "Mode1" 296.00 2560 2568 2600 2666 1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-3 "Mode0"
xrandr --addmode DP-3 "Mode1"
```

Yet still, when I set them with `xrandr --output DP-3 --mode Mode1`, the screen turns dark just as when using the pre-set 2560x1440 mode.

Comment: Personally, I can't see anything wrong with your custom added modes but only thing I would suggest is to try creating a modeline with `cvt` in reduced blanking mode e.g. `cvt -r 2560 1440 60`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it, and the result is the same.